# Get a value from Firebase database using Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to provide a reference, from which only the value would be printed. For example, I'm wishing to get the output as "80" for the key "experience".
[an example path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM2xB.png)

```
    ref = db.reference(f"{user}")
    output = ref.get()  
    await ctx.send(output)
```

This code's output is going to be "{'ATK': 1, 'DEF': 1, 'experience': 80}" which is not desired.
Since the given output is a list, I have come up with a temporary fix:

```
    ref = db.reference(f"{user}")
    d1 = ref.order_by_key().get()
    data = list(d1.items())
    experience = list(data[2])
    output = experience[1]
    await ctx.send(output)
```

But apparently this is quite time-consuming as there might be a change in the order of keys, which mean I would have to rewrite the code above. Is there a quicker way to access a value, given a reference (and a key)?

Comment: What would you get when you convert it into a list using `list(d1.items())`? If possible, convert it into a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). If you want to automate it (which may take more time to run) than manually having to rewrite code often as the keys' order may change, you can probably loop through the items and check if it contains an expected value. If you get a dictionary-like object, you can get the value using the string key. [See this.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary-get-method/)

Comment: I think it would be `{'ATK': 1, 'DEF': 1, 'experience': 80}` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a solution to this.

```
@bot.command()
async def retrievePlayerStats(message):
  PATK  = db.reference(f"{message.author.id}/ATK").get()
  PDEF  = db.reference(f"{message.author.id}/DEF").get()
```

By giving a very specific reference and using `get()`, you can access only the value of the key.